Can I override Highcharts legend auto changing?
I have a highchart graph (codebase is react) with the following legend layout:

But when the screen gets small enough, it auto flips to be:

I have tried adding "layout: 'horizontal'" in everywhere I reference the chart, but I am still seeing this UI.
I admit I am still getting to grips with both the codebase this is inside as well as Highcharts itself, but can anybody help me to keep the first layout? I don`t mind the scrolling functionality, but would prefer not to have to use it.
I admit also that there will be some UI amends for various languages making the content too wide, which is likely the cause of the switching, but I want to disable the auto flip part...
I would be fine with reducing the height of the vertical column layout, but changing the maxHeight of the legend values does not seem to work...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
